# Twitter-Bootstrap navigation header with three elements (iOS style)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to do an horizontal bar that mimics the Navigation view on iOS, thats saying:

> Back                   Logo                  SomeButton
>
> Left           Center                Right

After fiddling with many solutions I've been able to get something similar,  using

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="static/img_nav/logo_white_trans.gif"> </a>
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><a href="#"> &lt; Back</a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

with this CSS:

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    height: 20px;
}
```

When I do the browsing in my phone everything works as I expected, but when I go to larger screens, left and right buttons get together.

```
Left Right Center
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The reason for your issue is :

In `navbar-collapse` the `width` is `auto`, So

Set `width:100%` in your `navbar-header` tag

```
 <div style="width:100%" class="navbar-header navbar-collapse">
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/ILiiIaAf2g)

Comment: Thanks. I'm just starting with bootstrap and struggling to do basic things. Hopefully will be able to be more capable with time.